# How can I make this tab active by default?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have some tabs and I want to make the first tab active by default. Now, isn't active, only if I press a tab is working. I want to make the first tab active by default.

**here is my code:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <?php $count_contact = 0; ?>
    @foreach($user->contact as $contact)    
        <li class=<?php if($count_user == 0){ echo "active"; } ?> >
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact<?php echo $count_contact++; ?>">
                <?php $img = asset('thumbnail').'/'.$contact->profile_picture; ?>
                @if(@getimagesize($img))
                    <img class="img-circle noticeboard-profile-picture" src="{{ url('ass/50/50?'.$img) }}" alt=""></a>
                @else
                    <?php $img = "assets/img/user.jpg"; ?>
                    <img class="hover-effect" alt="" src="{{ url('ass/54/54?'.$img) }}" width="50px">
                @endif
            </a>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

the first tab has id contact0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you want to use is `$count_contact` instead of `$count_user`. Try to change :

```
<li class=<?php if($count_user == 0){ echo "active"; } ?> >
```

To :

```
<li class=<?php if($count_contact == 0){ echo "active"; } ?> >
```

Answer (score 1):

Blade provides `$loop` variable which you can access in the loop. So change your code to this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <?php $count_contact = 0; ?>
    @foreach($user->contact as $contact)    
        <li @if($loop->first) class="active" @endif>
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#contact<?php echo $count_contact++; ?>">
        <?php $img = asset('thumbnail').'/'.$contact->profile_picture; ?>
        @if(@getimagesize($img))
            <img class="img-circle noticeboard-profile-picture" src="{{ url('ass/50/50?'.$img) }}" alt=""></a>
        @else
        <?php $img = "assets/img/user.jpg"; ?>
            <img class="hover-effect" alt="" src="{{ url('ass/54/54?'.$img) }}" width="50px">
           @endif
           </a>
       </li>
    @endforeach

</ul>
```

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: here is the documentation for [loop](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable).